# How do I encode a type that requires a particular superclass and interface implementation?

Tags: typescript, types

The starting point is that there's a library class I want to extend. In my particular case, I'm creating React components. Here's some simple filler code to represent a library class (to keep this example dependency-free).

```
class ReactComponent<T, U> {
    render() { return "some html"; }
}
```

I want to extend some of my React components with a custom interface. For example, I have a `Page` interface that represents components that are top-level pages, and they have properties like `title` and `shouldRenderInAppLayout`.

```
interface Page {
    title: string;
    shouldRenderInAppLayout: boolean;
}
```

Here's what my Page Components might look like:

```
class Homepage extends ReactComponent<any, any> implements Page {
    title: "Welcome";
    shouldRenderInAppLayout: true;

    render() { return "some other html"; }
}
```

Finally, I want to write a function that utilizes objects that are React `Component`s, and also `Page`s:

```
function customRender(component: typeof ReactComponent & Page) {
    if (component.shouldRenderInAppLayout) {
        // layout code
    }
    // code to render component here
}

customRender(Homepage);
```

But this fails with the following error:

> Argument of type 'typeof Homepage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof ReactComponent & Page'.
>     Type 'typeof Homepage' is not assignable to type 'Page'.
>       Property 'title' is missing in type 'typeof Homepage'.

Here's a runnable example of the above code: https://glot.io/snippets/eoe0j7hyri

How can I represent the type of `customRender`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense. You have instance properties you want to examine, but React components are passed around as constructor functions and you *definitely* should not be reaching into the class instances from the outside to query the instantiations' properties or methods.

The code as written just isn't factored properly. React is going to instantiate the class *after* you've attempted to read `shouldRenderInAppLayout`. You need some wrapping object to represent the flag and the thing-to-possibly-render.

Comment: I totally hear you out, and I'm adjusting my question accordingly; but I do want to note that this example, which is pure TypeScript with no dependencies, fails: I don't know how to represent "give me a type that extends this class and implements this interface".

I will revisit my usage of this with React; but in general, I want to know how to express this as a type.

Comment: Ohhhh, wait, I think I see the problem: `Homepage` needs to be instantiated, not passed around as a constructor. The blurred meaning of a "class" in JS/TS, especially with React, confused me.

Comment: I understand what you mean; I think this resolves my question. Thank you Ryan.